# Improving path followed by finger in canvas

Tags: android, canvas

When I implement drawing a path on canvas it works well but it has a very bad quality and very laggy for the path to follow your finger, but in some paint apps it runs very good and the path follows your finger very quickly and seems as if you are really using a pen, does anyone knows what extras are used by such apps or any documents around.

Comment: Read https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/smooth-signatures-9d92df119ff8#.tufuma26q  its a great intro on it.  The TLDR-  don't forget about the getHistoricalX/getHistoricalY and to quadTo the points.

Comment: @GabeSechan I checked this one before, yes it is a good intro but it only specifies how to use HistoricalX and HistoricalY....I need to know how to make the path really smooth and easy to follow any other advanced options?